# Cordova : get color of where I clicked

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova 6.1.1. I have an image on my screen, I want to know the pixel color where I clicked. I know how to do it in native android but I want to do it in cordova.

Below is the code that I am using to capture the touch event.

```
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
  console.log('got click start event' + event);
});
```

I am getting Touch event but not sure how to identify the pixel and its color of touch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript we can do this. But instead of `<image>` you have to use `<canvas>`. in your event listener function put this code.

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = 'image.jpg';
var x1, y1, x2, y2;   // change your coordinates value according to your need;  
x1 = 1;  
y1 = 1;
x2 = 0;
y2 = 0;
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
data = context.getImageData(x1, y1, x2, y2).data;
```

Then data is the array having color of the pixels. The array will have r, g, b and a values.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the touch element using following code,

```
function touchStart(event){
  var currentElement = event.target;
}
```

Once you got touch element, getting its attributes should be straight forward.